# C# equivalent to Delphi High() and Low() functions for arrays that maintains performance?

Tags: c#, arrays, delphi, iteration, dimensions

In Delphi there are the Low() and High() functions that return the lowermost and uppermost index dimensions for an Array.  This helps eliminate error prone *for loops* for iterating an array that might fall victim to an insidious +1/-1 array boundary error, like using **<=** when you meant **<** for the terminating condition in the *for loop* statement.

Here's an example for the Low/High functions (in Delphi):

```
for i := Low(ary) to High(ary) do
```

For now I'm using a simple *for loop* statement in C#:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ary.Length; i++)
```

I know there is the Array method **GetDimension(N)** but that has its own liabilities since I could introduce an error by accidentally using the wrong dimension index.  I guess I could do something with enumerators, but I worry that there would be a significant performance cost when scanning a large array compared to using a *for loop*.  Is there an equivalent to High/Low in C#?

Answer (score 11):

The C# equivalent to the intrinsic `low(ary)` and `high(ary)` functions  are, respectively, `0` and `ary.Length-1`. That's because [C# arrays are zero based](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d.aspx#sectionToggle0). I don't see any reason why the `Length` property of an array should have performance characteristics that differ from Delphi's `high()`.

In terms of performance, the big difference between a Pascal `for` loop and that used by C derived languages concerns evaluation of the termination test. Consider a classic Pascal `for` loop:

```
for i := 0 to GetCount()-1 do
  ....
```

With a Pascal `for` loop, `GetCount()` is evaluated once only, at the beginning of the loop.

Now consider the equivalent in a C derived language:

```
for (int i=0; i<GetCount(); i++)
  ....
```

In this loop, `GetCount()` is evaluated every time round the loop. So in a language like C#, you would need a local variable to avoid calling that function over and over.

```
int N = GetCount();
for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
  ....
```

In the case of an array, if the optimiser could be certain that `ary.Length` did not mutate during the loop, then the code could be optimised by the compiler. I personally do not know whether or not the C# optimiser does that, but please refer to the comments for some more information.

Before you start re-writing your loops to use local variables containing the length of the array, check whether or not it makes any difference. Almost certainly it won't. The difference between Pascal and C-like for loops that I outline above is probably more significant in semantic terms than performance.

---

The language that I am particularly envious of is D. Here you can use a `foreach` loop that presents each item in an array as a reference, and thus allows you to modify the contents of the array:

```
void IncArray(int[] array, int increment) {
    foreach (ref e; array) {
        e += increment;
    }
}
```

Comment: the expression I posted previously works in the debugger immediate window while debugging C# code, but throws `InvalidCastException` if you try it in compile C# source code... interesting

Comment: @280Z28 It's an interesting curiosity, I agree. But perhaps off topic here.

Comment: If it were allowed in C#, then you could definitely create an array that doesn't use [0, Length) as bounds. You can still create such an array in C#, but it will have the type `IList<byte>` instead of `byte[]`.

Comment: Yup. I put in a link to the MSDN docs for C# arrays to guard against your comments!  ;-)

Comment: The documentation you linked to is correct for `byte[]` but not for `byte[,]` (or other multidimensional arrays). In C#, a `byte[,]` does not have to be indexed from [0, 0].

Comment: @280Z28 If you think that the MS documentation is wrong, submit an issue to them. I suspect that we are talking about different things. I'm talking about C# language arrays. I think you are talking about the .net `Array` class. I realise that the latter is used to implement the former.

Comment: The .NET optimizer will optimize `for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)` only if `arr` is a local variable. If it's a field, the optimization cannot be performed (because another method might change `arr` to point to a different array object).

Answer (score 4):

In C# the lower boundary is always zero, so the equivalent of `Low(ary)` is just `0`.

For a single dimension array, the equivalent of `High(ary)` is `ary.Length - 1`. (For multi dimensional arrays you would need more than one loop anyway.)

Answer (score 1):

Can you just use `foreach` statement instead?
like

```
foreach(int i in ary)
{
. . .
}
```

Comment: I frequently have to modify the elements of the array and the iteration variable of a foreach statement is not mutable.

Comment: @RobertOschler Probably should be stated in the question.

Answer (score 1):

[Boundary(int Dimension)]

These boundary functions provide the start and end point for the user specified dimension of any array. A second dimension would be noted with a 1, instead of a zero, and so on.

```
for (int i = ary.GetLowerBound(0); i <= ary.GetUpperBound(0); i++ )
{}
```

Comment: Are you sure your code snippet is enough? Just look on the other answers - they all have a good explanation part while your answer is low quality.

Comment: The answer is brief and an explanation might be nice but the question is `Is there an equivalent to High/Low in C#?`. They have provided that.

Comment: Sometimes less is more, and sometimes a little bit of trial and error work makes a person a better programmer.